# What is the meaning of 'in some ways'?

Tags: meaning

I'm having trouble understanding this phrase as it is used here:

> In some ways our definition of local compactness is not satisfying.

and the dictionaries do not help. Could you help to understand the uses of it?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the ELL. Your question is far too vague. Please give a particular context where the meaning of this phrase is not clear to you, and explain why.

Comment: @fev The context-phase is: "In some ways our definition of local compactness is not satisfying".

Comment: @JohnMars, that context-phrase agrees with what I have in mind in my answer below; I did not see it until now after having already posted. It means that "some parts of" or "some approaches to" or "in some ways of thinking about" our definition are not satisfying, but some are. I consider it rather informal.

Comment: @SarahBowman your answer really helped me. Thank you!

Comment: @JohnMars, now I got it figured out. I thought I should include your context phrase in my answer and explain it there, but I failed to look at the question. Now I see that you inserted it there. So now I inserted a new part in my answer to include it. I am so glad my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "in some ways" is often used in the vernacular to introduce the concept that there are a number of ways to think about something. I will use a few examples from everyday life to illustrate. In the end I will show how it applies to your context phrase.

**Example 1: Student and Teacher**

The teacher asks the class a question. A student provides a lengthy, but rather long-winded and wordy answer, then asks, "Does that make sense?"

"In some ways," says the teacher. Then the teacher explains the parts of the answer that make sense, and why they make sense. The teacher also explains which parts are wrong and why they are wrong. In other words, certain parts of the answer can be accepted to the teacher's original question but certain parts cannot be accepted. The student's answer made sense *in some ways* but not in other ways.

**Example 2: Speaker & New City Plan**

A speaker presents the new plan for city development. Much study has already gone into the project. There are environmental issues, financial issues, conflict of interest issues.

"I know some of you sitting here listening to me tonight will be thinking this thing is never going to work out," the speaker is saying. "In some ways, I agree with you completely but in other ways I feel very optimistic."

The speaker then explains the reasons for feeling the plan won't work out and also the reasons for feeling optimistic that it will. *In some ways* the plan looks impossible but in other ways it looks possible.

**Application to Context Phrase**

The context phrase below was added to the question after the above was posted.

> In some ways our definition of local compactness is not satisfying.

As in the examples above, *in some ways* refers to various parts of the "definition of local compactness" that are and are not satisfying.

*In some ways* can mean one of the following:

- some parts of
- some approaches to
- in some ways of thinking about

I consider it rather informal.

**Summary**

That's the best I know to explain and illustrate. It's just a common way of speaking where I live in Canada.